# Animated div doesn't hide under parent

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, svg

The rocket I'm trying to give an infinite animation, [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/3aphq5eL/), doesn't hide under the parent div like the example. The rocket simply changes on the Y-axis and overlays all the other elements. The code to the project ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1vdnL4re/)):

```js
var rocket = document.querySelector('#rocket');

rocket.addEventListener('click', function() {

    this.classList.toggle('clicked');

  })
```

```css
/*=============================================
[ Page Setup ]
==============================================*/

body {
  background: #34495e
}
#pageWrap {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#rocket {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 150px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/*=============================================
[ Inactive State Styles ]
==============================================*/

#rocket .fire {
  display: none;
  fill: #FC0;
}
#rocket .rocket-inner {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(15px) translateX(-3px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(15px) translateX(-3px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(15px) translateX(-3px);
  -o-transform: translateY(15px) translateX(-3px);
  transform: translateY(15px) translateX(-3px);
  /*transition*/
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  -moz-transition: .3s;
  -o-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
}
#rocket .icon-circle {
  /*transition*/
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  -moz-transition: .2s;
  -o-transition: .2s;
  transition: .2s;
  fill: #22303e;
}
#rocket .large-window-path {
  /*transition*/
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  -moz-transition: .2s;
  -o-transition: .2s;
  transition: .2s;
  fill: #22303e;
}
#rocket .window {
  /*transition*/
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  -moz-transition: .2s;
  -o-transition: .2s;
  transition: .2s;
  fill: #22303e;
}
#rocket .wing-shadow {
  fill: #34495e
}
#rocket .rocket-bottom {
  fill: #34495e
}
#rocket .rocket-base {
  fill: #34495e
}
#rocket .rocket-shadow {
  fill: #34495e
}
#rocket .wing-base {
  fill: #34495e
}
/*=============================================
[ Hover Styles ]
==============================================*/

#rocket:hover .fire {
  display: block !important;
}
#rocket:hover .rocket-base {
  fill: #FFFFFF !important;
  stroke-width: 0px !important;
}
#rocket:hover .rocket-shadow {
  fill: #EDEDED !important;
  stroke-width: 0px !important;
}
#rocket:hover .icon-circle {
  fill: #282e3a !important;
  stroke: #fff !important;
  stroke-width: 7px !important;
}
#rocket:hover .window {
  fill: #28B767 !important;
  stroke-width: 0px !important;
}
#rocket:hover .wing-shadow {
  display: block !important;
  fill: #FC9252 !important;
}
#rocket:hover .wing-base {
  fill: #E16E36 !important;
  stroke-width: 0px !important;
}
#rocket:hover .rocket-bottom {
  fill: #E16E36 !important;
  stroke-width: 0px !important;
}
#rocket:hover .rocket-inner {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0px) translateX(-3px) !important;
  -moz-transform: translateY(0px) translateX(-3px) !important;
  -ms-transform: translateY(0px) translateX(-3px) !important;
  -o-transform: translateY(0px) translateX(-3px) !important;
  transform: translateY(0px) translateX(-3px) !important;
}
/*=============================================
[ Clicked Styles ]
==============================================*/
/* THIS IS FOR THE ROCKET .clicked ANIMATION

*/

#rocket.clicked .fire {
    display:block !important;
}
#rocket.clicked .rocket-base  {
    fill: #FFFFFF !important;
    stroke-width: 0px !important;
}
#rocket.clicked .rocket-shadow {
    fill: #EDEDED !important;
    stroke-width: 0px !important;
}
#rocket.clicked .icon-circle {
    fill: #282e3a !important;
    stroke: #fff !important;
    stroke-width: 7px !important;
}
#rocket.clicked .window{
    fill: #28B767 !important;
    stroke-width: 0px !important;
}
#rocket.clicked .wing-shadow {
    display: block !important;
    fill: #FC9252 !important;
}
#rocket.clicked .wing-base {
    fill: #E16E36 !important;
    stroke-width: 0px !important;
}
#rocket.clicked .rocket-bottom {
    fill: #E16E36 !important;
    stroke-width: 0px !important;
}
#rocket.clicked .rocket-inner {
      -moz-transform: translate(0px, 50px);
  -ms-transform: translate(0px, 50px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 50px);
  transform: translate(0px, 50px);
  -webkit-animation: loading .8s infinite linear;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
}


/*=============================================
[ KeyFrame Animations ]
==============================================*/
/* THIS IS FOR THE ROCKET .clicked ANIMATION

*/
@-webkit-keyframes loading {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 50px);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, -50px);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes loading {
  from {
    -moz-transform: translate(0px, 50px);
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: translate(0px, -50px);
  }
}
@-o-keyframes loading {
  from {
    -o-transform: translate(0px, 50px);
  }
  to {
    -o-transform: translate(0px, -50px);
  }
}

@keyframes fireSmall {
  10% {
    transform: rotate(17deg) translateY(1px)
  }
  20% {
    transform: rotate(-13deg) translateY(2px)
  }
  30% {
    transform: rotate(21deg) translateY(3px)
  }
  40% {
    transform: rotate(-34deg)translateY(4px)
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(24deg) translateY(5px)
  }
  60% {
    transform: rotate(-17deg) translateY(6px)
  }
  70% {
    transform: rotate(31deg) translateY(7px)
  }
  80% {
    transform: rotate(-28deg) translateY(8px)
  }
  90% {
    transform: rotate(14deg) translateY(9px)
  }
  99% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(10px)
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fireSmall {
  10% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(17deg) translateY(1px)
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-13deg) translateY(2px)
  }
  30% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(21deg) translateY(3px)
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-34deg)translateY(4px)
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(24deg) translateY(5px)
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-17deg) translateY(6px)
  }
  70% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(31deg) translateY(7px)
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-28deg) translateY(8px)
  }
  90% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(14deg) translateY(9px)
  }
  99% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(10px)
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes fireSmall {
  10% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(17deg) translateY(1px)
  }
  20% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-13deg) translateY(2px)
  }
  30% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(21deg) translateY(3px)
  }
  40% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-34deg)translateY(4px)
  }
  50% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(24deg) translateY(5px)
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-17deg) translateY(6px)
  }
  70% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(31deg) translateY(7px)
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-28deg) translateY(8px)
  }
  90% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(14deg) translateY(9px)
  }
  99% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(10px)
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fireLeft {
  6% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(25deg)
  }
  15% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-19deg)
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(25deg)
  }
  32% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg)
  }
  46% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(22deg)
  }
  54% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-29deg)
  }
  61% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(32deg)
  }
  74% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-9deg)
  }
  83% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(16deg)
  }
  99% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes fireLeft {
  6% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(25deg)
  }
  15% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-19deg)
  }
  25% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(25deg)
  }
  32% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-30deg)
  }
  46% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(22deg)
  }
  54% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-29deg)
  }
  61% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(32deg)
  }
  74% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-9deg)
  }
  83% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(16deg)
  }
  99% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
}
@keyframes fireMiddle {
  10% {
    transform: rotate(25deg)
  }
  20% {
    transform: rotate(-25deg)
  }
  30% {
    transform: rotate(30deg)
  }
  40% {
    transform: rotate(-22deg)
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(29deg)
  }
  60% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg)
  }
  70% {
    transform: rotate(37deg)
  }
  80% {
    transform: rotate(-15deg)
  }
  90% {
    transform: rotate(16deg)
  }
  99% {
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fireMiddle {
  10% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(25deg)
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-25deg)
  }
  30% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg)
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-22deg)
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(29deg)
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg)
  }
  70% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(37deg)
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg)
  }
  90% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(16deg)
  }
  99% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes fireMiddle {
  10% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(25deg)
  }
  20% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-25deg)
  }
  30% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(30deg)
  }
  40% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-22deg)
  }
  50% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(29deg)
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg)
  }
  70% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(37deg)
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-15deg)
  }
  90% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(16deg)
  }
  99% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
}
@keyframes fireRight {
  15% {
    transform: rotate(17deg)
  }
  23% {
    transform: rotate(-13deg)
  }
  37% {
    transform: rotate(21deg)
  }
  45% {
    transform: rotate(-34deg)
  }
  54% {
    transform: rotate(24deg)
  }
  67% {
    transform: rotate(-17deg)
  }
  72% {
    transform: rotate(31deg)
  }
  84% {
    transform: rotate(-28deg)
  }
  96% {
    transform: rotate(14deg)
  }
  99% {
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fireRight {
  15% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(17deg)
  }
  23% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-13deg)
  }
  37% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(21deg)
  }
  45% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-34deg)
  }
  54% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(24deg)
  }
  67% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-17deg)
  }
  72% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(31deg)
  }
  84% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-28deg)
  }
  96% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(14deg)
  }
  99% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes fireRight {
  15% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(17deg)
  }
  23% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-13deg)
  }
  37% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(21deg)
  }
  45% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-34deg)
  }
  54% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(24deg)
  }
  67% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-17deg)
  }
  72% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(31deg)
  }
  84% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-28deg)
  }
  96% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(14deg)
  }
  99% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
}
@keyframes fillOpacity1 {
  0% {
    fill-opacity: 1;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    fill-opacity: 1;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    fill-opacity: 0;
    stroke-opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fillOpacity1 {
  0% {
    fill-opacity: 1;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    fill-opacity: 1;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    fill-opacity: 0;
    stroke-opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes fillOpacity1 {
  0% {
    fill-opacity: 1;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    fill-opacity: 1;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    fill-opacity: 0;
    stroke-opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes fillOpacity2 {
  0% {
    fill-opacity: 1;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    fill-opacity: 1;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    fill-opacity: 0;
    stroke-opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fillOpacity2 {
  0% {
    fill-opacity: 1;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    fill-opacity: 1;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    fill-opacity: 0;
    stroke-opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes fillOpacity2 {
  0% {
    fill-opacity: 1;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    fill-opacity: 1;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    fill-opacity: 0;
    stroke-opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes fillOpacity3 {
  0% {
    fill-opacity: 1;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
  }
  67% {
    fill-opacity: 1;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    fill-opacity: 0;
    stroke-opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fillOpacity3 {
  0% {
    fill-opacity: 1;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
  }
  67% {
    fill-opacity: 1;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    fill-opacity: 0;
    stroke-opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes fillOpacity3 {
  0% {
    fill-opacity: 1;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
  }
  67% {
    fill-opacity: 1;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    fill-opacity: 0;
    stroke-opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes rocektMove {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(20px)
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rocektMove {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px)
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(20px)
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes rocektMove {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px)
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(20px)
  }
}
/*=============================================
[ Animation Classes ]
==============================================*/

.fire {
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  /*animation-iteration-count*/
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  /*transform-origin*/
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  /*animation-direction*/
  -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
  -moz-animation-direction: normal;
  -ms-animation-direction: normal;
  -o-animation-direction: normal;
  animation-direction: normal;
}
#rocket:hover #fire-left {
  /*animation-delay*/
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 0s;
  -o-animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  /*animation-name*/
  -webkit-animation-name: fireLeft, fillOpacity1;
  -moz-animation-name: fireLeft, fillOpacity1;
  -ms-animation-name: fireLeft, fillOpacity1;
  -o-animation-name: fireLeft, fillOpacity1;
  animation-name: fireLeft, fillOpacity1;
  /*animation-duration*/
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.2s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 1.2s;
  -ms-animation-duration: 1.2s;
  -o-animation-duration: 1.2s;
  animation-duration: 1.2s;
}
#rocket:hover #fire-middle {
  /*animation-delay*/
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 0s;
  -o-animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  /*animation-name*/
  -webkit-animation-name: fireMiddle, fillOpacity1;
  -moz-animation-name: fireMiddle, fillOpacity1;
  -ms-animation-name: fireMiddle, fillOpacity1;
  -o-animation-name: fireMiddle, fillOpacity1;
  animation-name: fireMiddle, fillOpacity1;
  /*animation-duration*/
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
  -ms-animation-duration: 1s;
  -o-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}
#rocket:hover #fire-right {
  /*animation-delay*/
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 0s;
  -o-animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  /*animation-name*/
  -webkit-animation-name: fireRight, fillOpacity1;
  -moz-animation-name: fireRight, fillOpacity1;
  -ms-animation-name: fireRight, fillOpacity1;
  -o-animation-name: fireRight, fillOpacity1;
  animation-name: fireRight, fillOpacity1;
  /*animation-duration*/
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.3s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 1.3s;
  -ms-animation-duration: 1.3s;
  -o-animation-duration: 1.3s;
  animation-duration: 1.3s;
}
#rocket:hover #fire-small-left {
  /*animation-delay*/
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 0s;
  -o-animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  /*animation-name*/
  -webkit-animation-name: fireSmall, fillOpacity2;
  -moz-animation-name: fireSmall, fillOpacity2;
  -ms-animation-name: fireSmall, fillOpacity2;
  -o-animation-name: fireSmall, fillOpacity2;
  animation-name: fireSmall, fillOpacity2;
  /*animation-duration*/
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.3s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 1.3s;
  -ms-animation-duration: 1.3s;
  -o-animation-duration: 1.3s;
  animation-duration: 1.3s;
  /*transform-origin*/
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom;
  -moz-transform-origin: bottom;
  -ms-transform-origin: bottom;
  -o-transform-origin: bottom;
  transform-origin: bottom;
}
#rocket:hover #fire-small-right {
  /*animation-delay*/
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0.3s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 0.3s;
  -o-animation-delay: 0.3s;
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
  /*animation-name*/
  -webkit-animation-name: fireSmall, fillOpacity3;
  -moz-animation-name: fireSmall, fillOpacity3;
  -ms-animation-name: fireSmall, fillOpacity3;
  -o-animation-name: fireSmall, fillOpacity3;
  animation-name: fireSmall, fillOpacity3;
  /*animation-duration*/
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.6s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 1.6s;
  -ms-animation-duration: 1.6s;
  -o-animation-duration: 1.6s;
  animation-duration: 1.6s;
  /*transform-origin*/
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom;
  -moz-transform-origin: bottom;
  -ms-transform-origin: bottom;
  -o-transform-origin: bottom;
  transform-origin: bottom;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="pagewrap">

    <svg version='1.1' x='0px' y='0px' width='307px' height='283px' id='rocket'>

      <circle class='icon-circle' cx='147.5' cy='138.6' r='105.5' />

      <g class='rocket-inner'>
        <path class='fire' id='fire-middle' d='M148.891,179.906c3.928,0,7.111,3.176,7.111,7.094 c0,7.78-7.111,16-7.111,16s-7.111-8.349-7.111-16C141.78,183.082,144.963,179.906,148.891,179.906z' />

        <path class='fire' id='fire-right' d='M154.063,181.092c3.577-1.624,7.788-0.048,9.408,3.52 c3.216,7.084,0.139,17.508,0.139,17.508s-9.927-4.662-13.09-11.63C148.9,186.923,150.487,182.715,154.063,181.092z' />

        <path class='fire' id='fire-left' d='M143.392,182.519c3.25,2.207,4.098,6.623,1.896,9.864 c-4.372,6.436-14.873,9.238-14.873,9.238s-1.191-10.902,3.108-17.23C135.725,181.149,140.143,180.312,143.392,182.519z' />

        <path class='fire' id='fire-small-left' d='M143.193 187.531c2.226 0.4 3.7 2.6 3.2 4.8 c-0.875 4.407-5.829 8.264-5.829 8.264s-3.09-5.53-2.229-9.865C138.807 188.5 141 187.1 143.2 187.531z' />

        <path class='fire' id='fire-small-right' d='M152.089 188.599c2.043-0.985 4.496-0.132 5.5 1.9 c1.952 4 0.3 10.1 0.3 10.107s-5.795-2.56-7.713-6.541C149.186 192 150 189.6 152.1 188.599z' />

        <path class='rocket-bottom' d='M157.069 171.31h-3.292c-1.562-0.048-3.178-0.076-4.846-0.076 s-3.284 0.028-4.846 0.076h-3.292c-7.277-7.938-12.371-26.182-12.371-47.434c0-28.54 9.182-51.676 20.508-51.676 c11.327 0 20.5 23.1 20.5 51.676C169.44 145.1 164.3 163.4 157.1 171.31z'
        />

        <path class='wing-base' d='M166.678 127.161c0 0 17.7 3.3 12.9 48.099l-18.06-14.05 L166.678 127.161z' />

        <path class='wing-shadow' d='M158.225 140.336c10.481-5.584 22.7 22.2 21.4 34.9 l-18.06-14.05C161.542 161.2 156.1 144.3 158.2 140.336z' />

        <path class='wing-base' d='M135.131 161.21l-18.06 14.1 c-4.805-44.793 12.924-48.099 12.924-48.099L135.131 161.21z' />

        <path class='wing-shadow' d='M135.131 161.21l-18.06 14.1 c-1.367-12.746 10.896-40.509 21.377-34.924C140.614 144.3 135.1 161.2 135.1 161.21z' />

        <path class='rocket-base' d='M162.728 167.358c-3.778-0.623-8.573-0.996-13.796-0.996 s-10.018 0.373-13.795 0.996c-5.033-10.186-8.257-25.808-8.257-43.338c0-30.688 9.873-55.566 22.052-55.566 s22.053 24.9 22.1 55.566C170.984 141.6 167.8 157.2 162.7 167.358z'
        />

        <path class='rocket-shadow' d='M145.464 166.417c19.578-40.575 7.26-85.229 4.112-98.067 c11.88 0.9 21.4 25.4 21.4 55.525c0 17.529-3.225 33.152-8.257 43.337c0 0-3.786-0.472-8.069-0.697 S145.464 166.4 145.5 166.417z' />

        <circle class='window' cx='148.9' cy='111.3' r='10.5' />

        <circle class='window' cx='148.9' cy='132.4' r='5.2' />
      </g>

    </svg>


  </div>
```

Comment: The [link](http://codepen.io/JDreau/pen/PwEpap) has been updated to show what I meant. But it still isn't like the example project :/

Answer (score 0):

First things first: you have a syntax error in your JS.

Second, I made you this codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EaQjdP

I think I see what you're trying to do, and I think it won't work. Here's the first (minor) problem: SVG elements are painted in the order that they appear in the SVG markup. Thus, your `<circle>` element will always be under the rocket.

The second problem is that your `<circle>` element describes the area you want to *show*, not the area you want to *hide*.

I recommend you look into [SVG clipping and masking](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Clipping_and_masking) if you want to use the `<circle>` element. Your other option is shrinking your `<svg>` element down to the size of your circle and using `border-radius: 50%; overflow: hidden; border: 5px solid white;` on that.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will look into it in a minute. I already made it into a codepen and had 1200 views so I wanted to create this animation but failed. I really hope this  will work.

Comment: I was attempting to do this with a clip-path but I can't get it to work either - at least not in Chrome. I can clip the circle but not the group. For some reason it doesn't apply it to the elements in the group.